# Como alterar valor de um objeto em php

Tags: php, json, stdclass

Estou passando um objeto criado num arquivo jQuery para o php e obtendo pelo seguinte código.

```html
$data = $_POST['data'];
$d = json_decode($data);
$user = $d->user;
$season = $d->season;
print_r($d);
```

O que esta me retornando o seguinte:

```html
stdClass Object
(
    [user] => 1
    [season] => 2016
    [week201548] => stdClass Object
        (
            [bloco] => Microciclo
            [day24112015] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [z1] => 0
                    [z2] => 0
                    [z3] => 0
                    [z4] => 0
                    [z5] => 0
                    [z6] => 0
                    [z7] => 0
                    [terrain] => Terreno
                    [rpe] => 7
                    [elevation] => 1861
                    [fc] => 140
                    [time] => 250
                    [distance] => 86
                    [training] => 

                    [color] => 
                )

            [day25112015] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [z1] => 0
                    [z2] => 0
                    [z3] => 0
                    [z4] => 0
                    [z5] => 0
                    [z6] => 0
                    [z7] => 0
                    [terrain] => Terreno
                    [rpe] => 7
                    [elevation] => 1861
                    [fc] => 140
                    [time] => 250
                    [distance] => 86
                    [training] => 

                    [color] => 
                )

            [day26112015] => stdClass Object
                (
```

A minha dúvida é, como faço para alterar apenas um valor deste objeto?
Por exemplo, só o `[elevation]` do `[day24112015]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você executou o `json_decode($data)`, você obteve como retorno um objeto. Para alterar o atributo do objeto da forma que você quer, faz-se assim:

```
$d->user->season->week201548->day25112015->elevation = 0; // novo valor do atributo do valor elevation
```

Se você tivesse, por exemplo, executado `json_decode($data, true)` (note o segundo argumento do método), você teria recebido um array associativo, o qual você poderia modificar da seguinte maneira:

```
$d['user']['season']['week201548']['day25112015']['elevation'] = 0; // novo valor do atributo do valor elevation
```

Comment: Puxa vida, eu tinha respondido isso e apaguei pq não sabia se estava certo por não ter experiencia com json kkkk

Comment: Simples assim.... eu estava pensando em algo parecido, mas como não estava conseguindo resolvi perguntar para tirar a dúvida. Obrigado @Rodrigo Rigotti.